# program not entering while loop?

Tags: java, sockets, loops, io, client-server

I am working on a program that connects to a server and talks back and forth.

The server sends a `String` initially and then I send the first letter back server sends the second and I send the third so on and so forth.

Whoever does not send the last letter of the string sends "done!".

My program is working up to the point of getting the string and breaking up into the chars, but will not enter the while loop it seems and I can't figure out why.

Below is my code and the test cases I am trying to pass.

Could someone explain why my code is not working (I think it has to do with the while loop), and what I need to do to fix it?

**my code**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Program2 {
static String rec;
public static void goClient(){
try{
String server = "localhost";
int port = 4321;
Socket socket = new Socket(server, port);
InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();
OutputStream outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(inStream);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outStream);


    rec = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(rec);


char[] array = new char[rec.length()];

for(int i = 0; i < rec.length(); i++){
    array[i] = rec.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}


    if(array.length % 2 == 0){
    while(scan.hasNext()){  
    for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x+=2){
    String str;
    str = Character.toString(array[x]);
    System.out.print(str);
    out.println(str);
    str = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print(str);
    }
    }   
    }
    if(array.length % 2 != 0){
        while(scan.hasNext()){
        for(int x = 0; x < array.length - 1; x+=2){
            String str;
            str = Character.toString(array[x]);
            System.out.print(str);
            out.println(str);
            str = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.print(str);
        }
        }
        out.println("done!");
       }

scan.close();
socket.close();

} catch (IOException e) {}
}
}
```

**Junit test cases**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Program2Test {
@Before
public void wait2SecondsBeforeEachTest() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep( 2000 );
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Test
public void test0() {
    Runnable             client = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Program2.goClient();
        }
    };
    final CountDownLatch gate   = new CountDownLatch( 1 );
    Runnable             server = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
            ServerSocket server = null;
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket( 4321 );

                Socket       client = server.accept();
                PrintWriter  out    = new PrintWriter( client.getOutputStream(), true );
                Scanner      in     = new Scanner    ( client.getInputStream() );

                out.println( "Lorem" );

                String actual = in.nextLine();
                assertEquals( "Incorrect result", "L", actual );

                out.println( "o" );

                actual = in.nextLine();
                assertEquals( "Incorrect result", "r", actual );

                out.println( "e" );

                actual = in.nextLine();
                assertEquals( "Incorrect result", "m", actual );

                out.println( "done!" );

                assertFalse( "Client hasn't closed its socket", in.hasNext() );

                client.close();

                gate.countDown();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    if (server != null) {
                        server.close();
                    }
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread serverThread  = new Thread( server );
    serverThread.start();
    Thread clientThread  = new Thread( client );
    clientThread.start();

    int count = 0;
    while (serverThread.isAlive() && count++ < 300) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep( 10 );
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    assertTrue( "Client did not arrive or did not finish correctly", gate.getCount() == 0 );
}
@Test
public void test1() {
    Runnable             client = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Program2.goClient();
        }
    };
    final CountDownLatch gate   = new CountDownLatch( 1 );
    Runnable             server = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ServerSocket server = null;
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket( 4321 );

                Socket       client = server.accept();
                PrintWriter  out    = new PrintWriter( client.getOutputStream(), true );
                Scanner      in     = new Scanner    ( client.getInputStream() );

                out.println( "Let it be." );

                String actual = in.nextLine();
                assertEquals( "Incorrect result", "L", actual );

                out.println( "e" );

                actual = in.nextLine();
                assertEquals( "Incorrect result", "t", actual );

                out.println( " " );

                actual = in.nextLine();
                assertEquals( "Incorrect result", "i", actual );

                out.println( "t" );

                actual = in.nextLine();
                assertEquals( "Incorrect result", " ", actual );

                out.println( "b" );

                actual = in.nextLine();
                assertEquals( "Incorrect result", "e", actual );

                out.println( "." );

                actual = in.nextLine();
                assertEquals( "Incorrect result", "done!", actual );

                assertFalse( "Client hasn't closed its socket", in.hasNext() );

                client.close();

                gate.countDown();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    if (server != null) {
                        server.close();
                    }
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread serverThread  = new Thread( server );
    serverThread.start();
    Thread clientThread  = new Thread( client );
    clientThread.start();

    int count = 0;
    while (serverThread.isAlive() && count++ < 300) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep( 10 );
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    assertTrue( "Client did not arrive or did not finish correctly", gate.getCount() == 0 );
}
@Test
public void test2() {
    Runnable             client = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Program2.goClient();
        }
    };
    final CountDownLatch gate   = new CountDownLatch( 1 );
    Runnable             server = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ServerSocket server = null;
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket( 4321 );

                Socket       client = server.accept();
                PrintWriter  out    = new PrintWriter( client.getOutputStream(), true );
                Scanner      in     = new Scanner    ( client.getInputStream() );

                out.println( "Upside Down" );

                String actual = in.nextLine();
                assertEquals( "Incorrect result", "U", actual );

                out.println( "p" );

                actual = in.nextLine();
                assertEquals( "Incorrect result", "s", actual );

                out.println( "i" );

                actual = in.nextLine();
                assertEquals( "Incorrect result", "d", actual );

                out.println( "e" );

                actual = in.nextLine();
                assertEquals( "Incorrect result", " ", actual );

                out.println( "D" );

                actual = in.nextLine();
                assertEquals( "Incorrect result", "o", actual );

                out.println( "w" );

                actual = in.nextLine();
                assertEquals( "Incorrect result", "n", actual );

                out.println( "done!" );

                assertFalse( "Client hasn't closed its socket", in.hasNext() );

                client.close();

                gate.countDown();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    if (server != null) {
                        server.close();
                    }
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread serverThread  = new Thread( server );
    serverThread.start();
    Thread clientThread  = new Thread( client );
    clientThread.start();

    int count = 0;
    while (serverThread.isAlive() && count++ < 300) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep( 10 );
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    assertTrue( "Client did not arrive or did not finish correctly", gate.getCount() == 0 );
}
}
```

**console output**

```
Lorem
L
o
r
e
m
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Program2Test$4.run(Program2Test.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Program2Test$6.run(Program2Test.java:199)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {}` is a bad idea.  Handle it somehow, even if it's just printing the stack trace.  That may give you an idea as to what's going on.

Comment: Added the print for stack trace, does not seem I am getting an IO exception. I added the output to the console from my print statements. it seems to be making it trough putting the the chars into and array and then failing which makes me think it is a while loop error of some sort which is causing the first test to fail and not close the socket witch is causing the other tests to fail and give a JVN error.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, it appears that your program tries to bind (reserve) an already used port, probably as a result of running the statement of `Program2Test`

```
server = new ServerSocket( 4321 );
```

You are also using port 4321 for the socket definition of `Program2`, i.e. in the statement

```
Socket socket = new Socket(server, port);
```

Check whether that creates a conflict on the client or the server side, or whether `JUnit` runs more than 1 times the `test2()` method.

Comment: I was told the JVN error is due to first test not passing correctly and not closing the socket so when the second and third tests try the socket is in use giving the error. for some reason my program is not reaching the part in the while loop as the print statements inside are not triggering.

Comment: This is similar to what I told you in the sense that test2() runs multiple times on the same port (4321). Try creating a stand-alone version of the server code, outside JUnit.